# Selecting on a many table using Linq

Tags: linq

I have a recipe table that has a related ingredients table
on one to many basis.

How do I select using Linq ingredients
that have a ingredientName column and it should contain
a specified word.

This is what I tried.

```
 IQueryable<OurRecipes.Domain.Linq2Sql.Recipe> recipes = _dbctx.Recipes.AsQueryable();

    foreach (string word in searchdata.Keywords)
    {
        recipes = recipes.Where(r => r.RecipeTitle.Contains(word));
        recipes = recipes.Where(r => r.Ingredients.Where(i => i.IngredientName.Contains(word)));
    }
```

I get cannot convert type 'etc' to bool error.

Any ideas
Malcolm

Answer (score 2):

The error lies here:

```
 recipes = recipes.Where(r => r.Ingredients.Where(i => i.IngredientName.Contains(word)));
```

The condition inside `Where` must return a boolean, in this case, the `r.Ingredients.Where(i => i.IngredientName.Contains(word))` will not return a boolean, and hence the error.

This is how you can fix the problem:

```
recipes = recipes.Where(i => i.Ingredients.Any(row=>row.IngredientName.Contains(word)));
```

Comment: +1, and the fix is to change that line to something like `recipes = recipes.Where(r => r.Ingredients.Count(i => i.IngredientName.Contains(word)) > 0);`

Comment: Your solution will not compile, because `i` is `Recipie`. It does not have `IngredientName`.

Answer (score 1):

```
r.Ingredients.Where(i => i.IngredientName.Contains(word)));
```

replace with

```
r.Ingredients.Any(i => i.IngredientName.Contains(word)));
```

---

Btw, I like SQL like syntax more as it more netural. The same:

```
from r in _dbctx.Recipes
where r.Ingredients.Any(i => i.IngredientName.Contains(word)));
select r;
```

This will select all recipies that has ingredients with name contains word.